# Action taking course only if two words match

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, match

I kinda have an idea but I really am not sure how to make it work, I only have fragments of multiple methods that don't seem to go head to head.

So I am turning to you for a glance of brilliance, let's say I am having 3 content containers with class :
about, portfolio and contact, about is visible and the other two are hidden.

I have a text box (or search box, whatever you want to call it) and what I want is if I write (and after I press enter) any of a number of words I set (in this case : poftfolio, portofoliu) the about container to fadeOut and the portfolio classed container to fadeIn. The same will go for about and contact.

I have no good Idea on how could I do this...
Any help ? Also if you have something set up, a fiddle would really come in handy to get a clear idea on how this works.

Thanks

PS: Probably one of the best functions I can think of is the jQuery function .is  -  a . is ( b ) but I don't know how to use it to compare with the text in the textbox.

I did try this but failed shortly :

```
$("#portfolio").hide();
$("#wrong").hide();

$('#search').keyup(function() {
    if ($("#portfolio").is("#search")) {

    $("#portfolio").fadeIn();

}else{
    $("#wrong").fadeIn();
}
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/WVHaT/17/)

Comment: When you say `$("#portfolio").is("#search")`, you get the element with an `id` of portfolio, then check if its `id` is search. It's always going to return false.

Comment: @Ninsly I kinda figured that out on the way...my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

html

```
<input id="search" type="text" />
<div id="content">
    <div id="about">about
        <br /><i>about content</i>
    </div>
    <div id="portfolio">portfolio
        <br /><i>portfolio content</i>
    </div>
    <div id="contact">contact
        <br /><i>contact content</i>
    </div>
</div>
```

js

```
var substringMatcher = function (strs, q, cb) {
    return (function (q, cb, name) {
        var matches, substrRegex;
        // an array that will be populated 
        // with substring matches
        matches = [];
        // regex used to determine if a string 
        // contains the substring `q`
        substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');
        // iterate through the pool of strings 
        // and for any string that
        // contains the substring `q`, 
        // add it to the `matches` array
        $.each(strs, function (i, str) {
            $("#search").val("");
            if (substrRegex.test(str) 
               || q.slice(0, 1) === str.slice(0, 1)) {
                // the typeahead jQuery plugin 
                // expects suggestions to a
                // JavaScript object, refer to 
                // typeahead docs for more info        
                matches.push(name(str));
            }
        });
        cb(matches);
    }(q, cb, function (n) {
        return {
            "content": n
        }
    }));
};

var _matches = $.map($("#content div"), function (v, k) {
    return [v.id]
});

var template = {
    "content": _matches
};
$("#content div:gt(0)").hide(0);
$('#search').focus().keyup(function (e) {
    var search = $(this);
    var _search = search.val();
    if (e.which === 13) {
        substringMatcher(template.content, _search, function (d) {
            $("#" + d[0].content).fadeIn(500).siblings().hide();
            search.val("");
        })
    }
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/2na7dyjf/

See, also [typeahead.js - examples](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/)

Comment: Both you and Roko have good/working answers/examples, only one thing missing in both, when you search in lowercase it's working but I need it to work when you have first letter uppercase and all letters uppercase as well since this will be used in phone searches too and most phones have default first letter upper. Thanks for everything btw.

Comment: In your example I think that would look something like 'var search = $('#search').val().toLowerCase();'

Comment: PS: I can't seem to be able to make #search work with a button press too...any idea why ? http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/35r0m6rc/10/

Comment: Tried attach `event` to `button` element ? See http://api.jquery.com/on/ "Description: Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements."

Answer (score 0):

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WVHaT/22/)

Add to all your `DIV` elements a `hidden` class

```
<div class="hidden" id="portfolio">Hello</div>
<div class="hidden" id="wrong">Not quite</div>
```

and try this:

```
$(".hidden").hide();

var searchID = "";

$('#search').keyup(function( e ) {
    searchID = $.trim( this.value.toLowerCase() );
    if( searchID && e.which===13){
       $(".hidden").hide();
       $('[id='+  searchID  +']').show();
    }
});
```

**Edit:** If you want to be sure you're targeting the `ID` strictly in lowercase simply add `.toLowerCase()`

If you want to make the above less strict, instead of using only `[id=` you can try other selectors like:

```
[id*=  Contains...
[id^=  Starts With...
[id$=  Ends With...
```

Comment: That would work only that it should show the content of the hidden classified containers only after hitting Enter, to avoid showing the container of the **#portfolio** after only pressing **p**

Comment: @Alin I know you requested it, I thought that this way it would actually be a feature. Editing my answer...

Comment: The update made now pointed out another bug, when you write **p** from portfolio and you erase it to write **w** from wrong, both of the Divs

Comment: Both you and guest271314 have good answers, only one thing missing in both, when you search in lowercase it's working but I need it to work when you have first letter uppercase and all letters uppercase as well since this will be used in phone searches too and most phones have default first letter upper. Thanks for everything btw.

Comment: @Alin you should explore a bit more the JS methods available. `.toLowerCase()` is what you need. We're not here do to the homework for you but to give you some basic idea. It's on to you to improve the code further for your exact needs.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I already did that on guest271314's method, i even commented that it would go like : var search = $('#search').val().toLowerCase(); I think you didn't see that. In the comment I left i wasn't asking you guys to do it, i just mentioned what I have to do further. I also thanked you for everything.

Comment: @Alin you're welcome! Thought you expected one to do every single line of code for you ;) Happy coding!